# Ionic using a condition to compare a string with data returned in an Observable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, observable

In this code I retrieve data about a country as an observable. I then try to compare my string this.city with this.capital which I retrieved from the Observable. If the two do not equal I want to display a new paragraph in the html by changing the hidden boolean to false. I know that this.city and the observable this.capital are not equal but it does not display the paragraph in the html after calling showHeader().
I wonder if you can compare Observable data with strings in this way?

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
    import { SettingsPage } from '../../pages/settings/settings';
    import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
    import { CityDataProvider } from '../../providers/city-data/city-data';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'page-home',
      templateUrl: 'home.html'
    })
    export class HomePage {
    
      hidden: boolean = true;
      hiddenTwo: boolean = true;
    
      city: string;
      cityData: any[];
      capital: string;
      cityLowerCase: string;
    
      constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private storage: Storage, private cdp: CityDataProvider) {
      }
    
      async ionViewWillEnter() {
        const data = await this.storage.get("city")
          .then((value) => {
            if (value == null) { this.hidden = false; } else if (value !== null) { this.hidden = true; }
            this.city = value;
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            alert("Error accessing storage.")
          })
    
        this.cdp.getCityData(this.city).subscribe(data => {
          this.cityData = data;
    
          this.capital = data[0].capital.toString().toLowerCase();
          this.cityLowerCase = this.city.toLowerCase();
    
         this.showHeader(this.cityLowerCase, this.capital);
    
        });
      }
    
      showHeader(a: string, b: string) {
        if (a != b){
          this.hiddenTwo = false;
        }
      }
    
      openSettingsPage() {
        this.navCtrl.push(SettingsPage);
      };`enter code here`
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using both `await` and `then` on `this.storage.get("city")`? You only need either one.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `then` on `this.storage.get("city")`, `this.city` has not been set yet when you call `this.cdp.getCityData(this.city)`. Just use `await` properly.

Also, some basic tips:

- `if(a == b){...} else if(a != b){...}` is essentially just `if(a == b){...}else{...}`
- `if(condition){value = true}else{value = false}` is essentially just `value = condition`

---

```
async ionViewWillEnter() {
    try
    {
        this.city = await this.storage.get("city");
        this.hidden = this.city == null;
    }
    catch (error)
    {
        alert("Error accessing storage.")
    }

    this.cdp.getCityData(this.city).subscribe(data =>
    {
        this.cityData = data;

        this.capital = data[0].capital.toString().toLowerCase();
        this.cityLowerCase = this.city.toLowerCase();

        this.showHeader(this.cityLowerCase, this.capital);

    });
}

showHeader(a: string, b: string) {
    this.hiddenTwo = a != b;
}
```